# Limit the number of external API calls per second

Tags: api, limit, wp-remote-post

I would like to use wp_remote_post to retrieve data from an external API. The matter is that the external API only accepts a maximum of 5 requests per second. However, depending on how many users are using the related feature on my website, my website may send more than 5 requests per second.
How can I, in Wordpress, enqueue (or limit) the output requests (or the use of wp_remote_post) in order to allow only 5 external API calls per second from my website ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this feature allowes users to pass data and based on that data the api will return specific data to that request? or does it return some fixed data?

Comment: Yes, it allows users to pass data, and the api will return specific data from the external website.

Comment: Ok, does the api return a error when you reach that limit? is it unique?

Comment: I have not tried to send more than 5 requests in one second, because it is already said in their docs that the api will return the following error:
{
  "code": 53,
  "message": "Too many requests",
  "description": "The application has made too many calls and has exceeded the rate limit for this service."
}

Comment: You could do a check for that code (**53**), if the response code equal to that code resend the request

Comment: By the way, I wish for this problem to happen often for you, if you have so much trafic in your site you are doing something great! keep it up! Hope you would have even more trafic =D

Comment: This *might* be a pretty good use-case for [Action Scheduler](https://actionscheduler.org/), or a similar implementation of a background queue... but maybe not at that high of a rate. Really, I think the best solution will heavily depend on what exactly you're exchanging with that API and what your "related feature" is/does. For managing that much traffic, I would be thinking about offloading that interaction to a long-running process, and maybe even throwing a caching layer into that process if it's appropriate.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast No need to check the error code because the provider is clear in the response to my mail : "5 TPS means that every secend you can made 5 calls. Rest of calls will be rejected with error response . It will be needed to resend them. Please do not take this limitation as a hindrance. There is a lot of users of our API and traffic is really hugh. This limitation enables to secure efectiveness for all our clients."